# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dense_to_dense_set_operation'

Tags: tensorflow

While executing `udc_train.py` of the [chatbot-retrieval project from GitHub](https://github.com/dennybritz/chatbot-retrieval), I got this exception at the end of training steps and at the beginning of evaluations step.  The problem seems that the following line of code returns `None` to the variable `_set_ops`:

```
_set_ops = loader.load_op_library(
resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("_set_ops.so"))
```

I could found no `_set_ops.so` or so in `tensorflow` library folder.

Any suggestions to resolve this problem?

My runtime: Amazon EC2 GPU Windows Instance.

**ANSWER:**
Submitted [this ticked](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6115) to the github community of tensorflow and a new release has been build as a fix.

(I couldn't submit my answer since due to lack of StackOverflow badges.  Anyone who is volunteer to submit this answer is more than welcome.  I will approve it as the answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP found answer:  [This was a bug in TensowFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6115) that has now been fixed.  All 1.0 and later builds of TensorFlow have this error corrected.